# DevExpress ASPxButton not updating all properties

Tags: css, winforms, devexpress, aspxgridview

OK, been a while but I'm really stumped on this one. I want to change the image source of an ASPxButton from the code behind (later I will add conditions). The ImageUrl property updates but the height, width and borderstyle are lost (image appears at it's own height & width with a thick black border).

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SyncStatus" VisibleIndex="0" Caption=" " Width="22px">
    <DataItemTemplate>
       <dx:ASPxButton runat="server" Image-Url="~/Images/Wizard/Wand24x24.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" 
        Border-BorderStyle="None" id="btnWiz" OnInit="btnWiz_Init"></dx:ASPxButton>
    </DataItemTemplate>
 </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>


    Protected Sub btnWiz_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btnWiz As ASPxButton = TryCast(sender, ASPxButton)
    Dim container As GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer = TryCast(btnWiz.NamingContainer, GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)

    btnWiz.ImageUrl = "~/Images/NewNote.png"
    btnWiz.Border.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
    btnWiz.Border.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(0)
    btnWiz.Height = Unit.Pixel(20)
    btnWiz.Width = Unit.Pixel(20)

End Sub
```

I tried adding this as a solution

```
 .dxbButton
   {
     border-style: none;
     height: 20px;
     width: 20px;
    }
```

but element inspection shows this is ignored. Please advise as ypu are able and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a minor syntax adjustment (as I suspected). The proper syntax is

```
    btnWiz.Image.Height = 20
    btnWiz.Image.Width = 20
```

and of course this is fully documented somewhere I'm sure. It also took care of the border issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your css styles are ignored because of your inline styles

**Height="20px" Width="20px" Border-BorderStyle="None"**

are generating inline styles and this is what you finally get:

```
<div style="border-style:None; height:20px; width:20px; -moz-user-select:none;" ...
```

That overrides your css

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Forgetting the dxbButton style I created (as a shot-in-the-dark), when the btnWiz_Init sub fires all the inline styles are lost, and the redundant ones that are part of the sub are NOT applied, except the ImgUrl property.